# Why is aurelia suddenly so slow?

Tags: aurelia

Within the last few updates to Aurelia I've noticed increasingly bad load times. I'm not talking about bundling load times, but dev load times on localhost. The Aurelia motto was that it would get out of your way and only be there if you needed it. With a ~10 second load time for my page, that's not getting out of my way. Simply making style changes to my site is a tediously slow process now.

I checked the skeleton navigation sample app to make sure this wasn't related specifically to my "custom" version and I got the same load times. 107 requests and an average of 9.5 seconds to load the page. How is this acceptable for even a dev environment?

Is there a way to bundle just the Aurelia code so it's "out of my way"? Again, this has only happened within the last few releases of Aurelia. I don't know which one specifically because it felt like such a gradual increase and only now am I noticing these long load times.

**Edit**
I did take note that these long load times started shortly after I updated Chrome and FireFox. I'm not sure if it's actually related, but I noticed big slowdowns after the update, specifically in Chrome (I use Chrome for the majority of my dev work).

For reference, here's the log. It seems there are two culprits taking up the majority of the time.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Everything evens out after that.
The results:
[image: results]

Comment: I doubt this is an Aurelia problem, this is more likely an issue with how you are loading your application. I'm guessing you're using JSPM/SystemJS to load it. I'd ask the question and point to JSPM/SystemJS to get some help in that regard.

Comment: Is there an alternative to jspm and systemJS if this is in fact a systemJS issue?

Comment: Yep, you can move to Webpack or the Aurelia CLI

Comment: Can you show where you are seeing 10 second load times?  From what I see there is less than 3 second load times which are still high but if you are serving from a local dev server in dev mode this is probably just due to a poor dev machine, not Aurelia

Comment: Also you ask how is it acceptable for a dev environment to load without bundling but I'd caution you to make sure you understand the difference between a dev server (your local machine which acts as a web server) and a production sever with bundling enabled.  For example a true prod server would use various techniques such as gzipping files and using cashing as well.  Of course locally you are refreshing every request.  Do you have enough RAM and ROM on your machine to support a modern web development stack?  If not can you trim down?

Comment: @PWKad That is quite a moot point since I've been using the same dev enviornment this entire time. The only difference is aurelia updates and SystemJS updates. I added the full images.

Comment: @PWKad I was not saying at all that I think it's unacceptable to load without bundling, I said it was unacceptable to have these kinds of load times even running in a dev enviornment. This has nothing to do with the performance of bundling at all.